# What is the return of the class?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi so I am a new developer for ios swift app

I have this problem that I understand the structure of oop but dont know how it works

let say if I have 2 class the first class is MYCustomInput and second class is MYCustomTextView

```
class MYCustomInput: UIView, UIMyCustomTextView {

   let customTextView = MYCustomTextView()

}

class MYCustomTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {

override init (frame: CGRect = CGRectZero, textContainer: NSTextContainer? = nil )
{
   super.init (frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
}
```

will actually customTextView being displayed? Because based on my understanding we didnt call any init with the frame and textContainer parameter. Instead we just called the () . So Which init actually I called and what will be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
class MYCustomTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {

    override init (frame:NSRect, textContainer:NSTextContainer? )
    {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    }

}
```

Auto complete will ask you for the frame and textContainer when you type:

```
let customTextView = MYCustomTextView(
```

Answer (score 0):

`MYCustomTextView` will only be displayed if it is added to the view on screen as a `subview` and also is set a valid `frame`.

```
let customTextView = MYCustomTextView()
customTextView.frame = CGRectmake(0,0,100,100)
self.view.addSubView(customTextView)
```